# Не могу разобраться gnuplot + tikz

Tags: lua, latex, gnuplot

Пытаюсь вывести график gnuplot в код tikz. Попробовал использовать в gnuplot терминал `set terminal lua tikz`.
Gnuplot выдал соответствующий код в окружении `\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot] ... \end{tikzpicture}`, то что и надо. Не могу понять как правильно использовать в документе в LaTeX. В окружении tikzpicture есть, например, `\draw[gp path] (1.196,2.963)--(1.376,2.963);`, что за gp path? На это возмущается pdflatex и выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для примера сделал простенький скрипт для gnuplot:

```
set term lua tikz latex color tightboundingbox 
set  out 'fig-1.tex'

set samples 200
set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'
set title 'Тригонометрические функции'
plot sin(x) with lines title '$\sin(x)$', cos(x) with lines title '$\cos(x)$'

unset out
set term wxt
```

И сделал для него простой документ в LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-1]\\  
    \input{fig-1}
\end{document}
```

В обоих случаях я использовал кодировку cp1251, но, думаю, это не принципиально. Теоретически, свежие версии gnuplot умеют работать и с UTF-8, но я сам не пробовал.

Собственно, самое важное, чтобы подружить LaTeX и gnuplot - нужно в документе LaTeX подключить пакет `gnuplot-lua-tikz`, который нужно добыть из установленного gnuplot. В действительности, нужно добыть не один, а два файла: 1) `gnuplot\share\texmf\tex\latex\gnuplot\gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty` и  2) `gnuplot\share\texmf\tex\generic\gnuplot\ gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex`. Возле первого файла можно почитать файл `README`, в котором описано, что можно сделать с этими двумя файлами - можно их честно скопировать в каталоги latex-а, но проще всего их положить в один каталог с документом и получившимся файлом от gnuplot. После этого документ нормально откомпилируется латехом.

Результат получился примерно такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое. Есть один непонятный момент, как выводить подписи к рисунку в математическом формате, то есть вместо x хотелось бы $x$, также и про тики на осях. Вот например на оси x есть отметки -10, -5, 0, 5, 10 (на Вашем рисунке), как их вывести в математическом формате $-10$, $-5$, $0$, $5$, $10$?

Comment: @Дмитрий, с подписями на осях всё просто, я легенду для примера именно в матмоде и вывел (в скрипте gnuplot): `title '$\sin(x)$'`. А вот с метками будет сложнее (много писать)... Скорее всего их тоже придётся ручками каждую обзывать с `$...$` либо в самом gnuplot, либо потом уже в файле с рисунком tikz.